# CSS: What is the selector for something that has a center tag in the middle of it?

Tags: css

I have

```
<div>
  <center>
    <img>
  </center>
</div>
```

I've tried div img, div center img, div > img, can't seem to get it right.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the center tag deprecated use styles instead e.g. margin: 0 auto;

Comment: does it actually matter what the markup is if you use css? As long as you can apply the css.

Comment: You told him to change the mark up, which assumes he can and doesn't answer the question

Comment: I said the center tag is deprecated? Didn't say to change the markup - I think there is a difference there

Answer (score 2):

`img`, `center img`, `div img` and `div center img` will all work. If you've tried this and it isn't working, it's not your selector that's failing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use center tags because [it has been deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_center.asp), to display something in the center try:

CSS:

```
div img {
text-align: center;
/*or margin: 0 auto;*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img>
 </div>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Doesn't answer or even address the question asked, you're simply critiquing his code.

Comment: No, but the `<center>` tag has in fact been deprecated, even if it is still supported, it shouldn't be used.

Comment: That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to get the `<img>`:

```
div img
```

should do it.

If you're trying to get `<div>`s that contain `<center>`, CSS doesn't do 'backtracking', so I'm not sure if that can be done.

As others have said, the `<center>` tag is not the best thing to use if you can avoid it.